# Custom and standard multiple filters in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a angularJS list that I would like to implement several filters, one will be a custom filter.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in cumulus.items | orderBy: predicate:reverse 
               | filter:listSearch | filter:filteredDates"
    ng-show="cumulus.items.length > 0">
</li>
```

My filter **listSearch** is working properly and I already made a function for the **filteredDates**
based in these two inputs and on button click:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="filter_startDate" />
<input type="date" ng-model="filter_endDate" />
<button id="search" ng-click="dateRange(filter_startDate,filter_endDate, cumulus.items)" >Search</button>
```

My function is returning the right items on the console, **all I need is to update the list with the returned value**. Here is the function:

```
$scope.dateRange = function (initialDateVal, endDateVal, cumulusItems) {
    filteredDates = [];
    var parsedinitialDateVal = Date.parse(initialDateVal);
    var parsedendDateVal = Date.parse(endDateVal);
    console.log("Initial date:", initialDateVal, parsedinitialDateVal);
    console.log("End date:", endDateVal, parsedendDateVal);
    if (cumulusItems && initialDateVal && endDateVal) {

        angular.forEach(cumulusItems, function (item) {

            parsedItemCreationDate = Date.parse(item.creationDate);

            if (parsedItemCreationDate >= parsedinitialDateVal
                && parsedItemCreationDate <= parsedendDateVal) {

                filteredDates.push(item);
            }                 

        });
    }

    console.log(filteredDates);
    return filteredDates;
};
```

Comment: You can assign it back to cumulus.items to update the list , but it will be filtered one, you can't have old data after assigning it to the original list variable.

Comment: @saravana It worked, is there a alternative? One that can work in a way I can correct the dates and update the value again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a custom predicate function:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in cumulus.items | orderBy: predicate:reverse 
               | filter:listSearch | filter: predicateFn">
</li>
```

```
$scope.predicateFn = function(element) {
    var parsedinitialDateVal = $scope.filter_startDate.valueOf();
    var parsedendDateVal = $scope.filter_endDate.valueOf();
    console.log("Initial date:", initialDateVal, parsedinitialDateVal);
    console.log("End date:", endDateVal, parsedendDateVal);

    var parsedItemCreationDate = Date.parse(element.creationDate);

    if (parsedItemCreationDate >= parsedinitialDateVal
        && parsedItemCreationDate <= parsedendDateVal) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
};
```

A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of the array, with the element, its index, and the entire array itself as arguments.

The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate returned `true` for.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `filter` Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: It worked with a minor adjustments. @georgeawg thanks